# How to use 'this' in multiple classes jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I am hiding 'hidden-items' class li elements using jquery and want to show them once **more tag** link is clicked. The jquery part is working, but all the list items are being showed.
I searched about this and found out about **'this'** selector. But I am confused on how to use this to show items that are close to **more tags** link.

```
<div class="tag-box">
 <ul class='gk-tags'>
  <li><a href='/category/economic' class='gk-tag'>Economic</a></li>
  <li><a href='/category/test' class='gk-tag'>Test</a></li>
  <li><a href='/category/sports' class='hidden-items gk-tag'>Sports</a></li>
  <li><a href='/category/health' class='hidden-items gk-tag'>Health</a></li>
 </ul>
 <a class='tag-show-more'>more tags</a>
</div>

<div class="tag-box">
 <ul class='gk-tags'>
  <li><a href='/category/test' class='gk-tag'>Test</a></li>
  <li><a href='/category/sports' class='hidden-items gk-tag'>Sports</a></li>
  <li><a href='/category/health' class='hidden-items gk-tag'>Health</a></li>
 </ul>
 <a class='tag-show-more'>more tags</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.hidden-items').hide();
  jQuery('.tag-show-more').click(function(){
     jQuery('.hidden-items').show();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the structure of your HTML, you can use [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) with `this` like:

```
jQuery(this).prev('.gk-tags').find('.hidden-items').show();
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.hidden-items').hide();
  jQuery('.tag-show-more').click(function(){
     jQuery(this).prev('.gk-tags').find('.hidden-items').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tag-box">
 <ul class='gk-tags'>
  <li><a href='/category/economic' class='gk-tag'>Economic</a></li>
  <li><a href='/category/test' class='gk-tag'>Test</a></li>
  <li><a href='/category/sports' class='hidden-items gk-tag'>Sports</a></li>
  <li><a href='/category/health' class='hidden-items gk-tag'>Health</a></li>
 </ul>
 <a class='tag-show-more'>more tags</a>
</div>

<div class="tag-box">
 <ul class='gk-tags'>
  <li><a href='/category/test' class='gk-tag'>Test</a></li>
  <li><a href='/category/sports' class='hidden-items gk-tag'>Sports</a></li>
  <li><a href='/category/health' class='hidden-items gk-tag'>Health</a></li>
 </ul>
 <a class='tag-show-more'>more tags</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `$(this)` for the selection of the current clicked element.

then use `.parents('.classNameOfParent')` to get the parent element

then hide the parent element

```
.hide()
```

you could do this like that:

```
 $(this).parents('.classNameOfParent').hide()
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('.hidden-items').hide();
      jQuery('.tag-show-more').click(function(){
         jQuery(this).closest(".tag-box").find('.hidden-items').show();
      });
    });
```

Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
jQuery(this).siblings('.gk-tags').find('.hidden-items').show();
```